# Only display tasks that belong to the current_user in the index action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I followed RailsCasts authentication from scratch (http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised) using the `bcrypt-ruby` gem and have the `best in place` gem in the app from another RailsCasts episode (http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing).

I have users, sessions, and tasks models. After the user logs in the application routes the user to `tasks#index`. Rather than having all tasks display, I want only the tasks that belong to the `current_user` in `tasks#index` to display.

My model associations look like this:
`Subscription: has_many :users,
Tasks: belongs_to :user,
User: has_many :tasks and belongs_to :subscription`

Users table has e-mail and password columns. Tasks table has content column.

The simple authentication from scratch creates a helper method in the application.rb file that I am having difficulty accessing in my tasks controller:

`def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user`

My tasks#controller index action looks like..

```
@tasks = Task.order("position")
@task = Task.new

end`
```

My tasks#index looks like this:

```
`
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
<li id="task_<%= task.id %>"><%= best_in_place task, :content %>
<%= link_to raw("&times;"), task, method: :delete, remote: true  %>
<span class="handle">&mdash;</span>
</li>
<% end %>`
```

`

```
<%= form_for(Task.new) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field  :content, :placeholder => "Add a new task here" %>
<% end %>
```

`

How can I restrict tasks to only the tasks created by the current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the User has many Tasks, in your tasks controller you can use the below to restrict the tasks to the current users as per below...

```
@tasks = @current_user.tasks.order("position")
@task = Task.new(:user => @current_user)
```

Comment: Thanks Norto23. I was able to add this code with no errors. I noticed when loading the index file no tasks are appearing now. I loaded the rails console and rank Task.all and noticed in each task the user_id is nil. It looks like the user_id isn't being set when creating a task.

Comment: Good to hear it worked! Please accept the answer by ticking the green tick on this answer.

Comment: Thanks. I guess a new problem cropped up with the user_id not being set.

Answer (score 0):

The other way by accessing a method created in Task Model :

```
app/views/index.html.erb

def index
     @tasks = current_user_tasks(current_user)
end

app/model/Task.rb

def current_user_tasks(user)
Task.where("tasks.user_id = ?", user.id).order('created_at asc').first
end
```

Hope That will fix your Issue !